# Forcing a Route to my API

Tags: c#, routes, asp.net-web-api2

I have these 2 apis in my API Controller (MVC5):

```
    [HttpGet]
    [HttpPost]
    public RestErrorHandler Add([FromBody]Models.Customer customer)
    {
        try
        {
          //do something...
            return new RestErrorHandler { Error = res.ErrorMessage, Location = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new RestErrorHandler { Error = ex.ToString(), Location = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name };
        }
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [HttpPost]
    public RestErrorHandler Delete([FromBody]Models.Customer customer)
    {
        try
        {
          //do something
            return new RestErrorHandler { Error = res.ErrorMessage, Location = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new RestErrorHandler { Error = ex.ToString(), Location = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name };
        }
    }
```

My client call is this:

```
var response = client.PostAsync(string.Format("http://my_uri/api/Customer/" + action), contentPost).Result;
```

Where 'action' can be 'Add' or 'Delete'.

Testing the delete it tells me this error:

```
Multiple actions were found that match the request:
```

To try and 'force' it to go to the correct way I added a Route tag to my method in my API:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Customer/Delete/Customer")]
    public RestErrorHandler Delete([FromBody]Models.Customer customer)
    {
        try
        {
            //do something
            return new RestErrorHandler { Error = res.ErrorMessage, Location = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new RestErrorHandler { Error = ex.ToString(), Location = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name };
        }
    }
```

But it calls my 'Add' api..?

What am I missing please?

Comment: You should not use get and post on the same method.

Comment: @StephenBrickner If I am returning something from the api I would also need to use a get. else it does not work..

Comment: It will work without using GET.

Comment: @StephenBrickner I am publishing and testing now. Thanks :)

Comment: No problem, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of these methods are POST's, remove GET.

```
[RoutePrefix("api")]
public class YourController: ApiController
{
    [HttpPost, Route("customers/add")]
    public RestErrorHandler Add([FromBody]Models.Customer customer)
    {
            try
            {
              //do something...
                return new RestErrorHandler { Error = res.ErrorMessage, Location = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name };
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return new RestErrorHandler { Error = ex.ToString(), Location = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name };
            }
    }

    [HttpPost, Route("customers/remove")]
    public RestErrorHandler Delete([FromBody]Models.Customer customer)
    {
            try
            {
                //do something
                return new RestErrorHandler { Error = res.ErrorMessage, Location = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name };
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return new RestErrorHandler { Error = ex.ToString(), Location = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name };
            }
    }
}

public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
     var configuration = new HttpConfiguration();

     //for route attributes on controllers
     configuration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
}

var response = await client.PostAsync("http://my_uri/api/customers/add", contentPost);
```

Postman
[image]

Comment: I updated the answer. On top of the class you'll see a RoutePrefix attribute. It keeps you from having to add it all the way down your methods.

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)